# Using define inside of a function

Tags: php

I am trying to define a constant inside of a function but I keep getting a syntax error. If I define this at the top of the file outside of the function and class it works `define('SALT_LENGTH', 9);` As soon as I put this inside the class or function I get syntax error I have also tried `const SALT_LENGTH = 9;` but it is the same issue. I have been searching around for answers but I am not finding anything.

```
class userFunctions{

//Generate an encrypted password method
    public function generateHash($password, $salt = null)

{
    if ($salt === null) {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    } else {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
        return $salt . sha1($salt . $password);
}
    //End of generate encrypted password method
}
```

Comment: define is a function you can't just call it while you're not inside a function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to use the 'self' keyword.

Like this,

class userFunctions{

```
const SALT_LENGTH = 5; // define constant 


public function generateHash($password, $salt = null)

{

    if ($salt === null) {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, self::SALT_LENGTH);
    } else {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, self::SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($salt . $password);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please use constructor in your class. Change any value you prefer for SALT_LENGTH. I chose 50. Below is the code.

```
 function __construct() {
        define('SALT_LENGTH','500');
 }
```